# How do I chose the next best option

Tags: vb.net, browser, vb.net-2010

I have a vb program which uses the built in web browser to find a specific drop down menu on a site and chose the size which the user has entered. The website changes the value for each different item so I must find the correct option using the following code:

```
Dim element As HtmlElement = WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("select").Cast(Of HtmlElement).First(Function(el) el.GetAttribute("name") = "size")
    element.GetElementsByTagName("option").Cast(Of HtmlElement).First(Function(el) el.InnerText = Form1.cmbSize1.Text).SetAttribute("selected", "selected")
```

This works to set the dropdown menu to the correct size if it is available but if for example the user enters size as : 'Small' and it isn't present I would like the program to add the next size for example : 'Medium'

```
<select id="size" name="size">
<option value="26881">Medium</option>
<option value="26882">Large</option>
<option value="26883">XLarge</option>
</select>
```

By default the website loads with the default size 'Medium' if the user entered size but I have a function which adds the item to the users cart afterwards and if the size entered isn't present for some reason it will not add to the cart 
the code for adding to cart is:

```
  For Each addtobasket As HtmlElement In WebBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("input")
        If addtobasket.OuterHtml.Contains("add to basket") Then
            addtobasket.InvokeMember("click")
            Return
        End If
    Next
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Jeez, how many are trying to make a bot for Supreme New York?? Make a list of existing sizes then check for the specified size, and if it doesn't exist you search for the next one in the list.

Comment: Too many. What do you mean by make a list of existing sizes?

Comment: @VisualVincent any ideas?

Comment: Make a list or array holding all standard sizes (ex: `{"Small", "Medium", "Large", "XLarge"}`). Then loop though all options and check for the specified size. If it doesn't exist then check for the next best thing. Using your array's index of the specified size you can increment it by one to start checking for the next item.

Comment: **For example:** User specified "Medium" (index 1 in this case) -> Loop through options -> Medium not found -> Check for next size (increment index by one = index 2) -> Check for the next item (index 2 = "Large").

Comment: thanks man going to try implement it now